# Pomodoro Timer REACTJS not working - useState not updating

Tags: reactjs, timer, mern

I'm quite new to ReactJS and have been working on a Pomodoro Timer. How it works is that whenever the "Work Timer" reaches zero, it switches to the "Break Timer".

const [secondsLeft, setSecondsLeft] = useState(newTimer.work);

However,
this line: setSecondsLeft(nextSeconds); **// This does not update secondsLeft**
under useEffect, does not update the secondsLeft which results in the timer for the break to display wrongly.

Could use some advice to make this work.

Thanks!

```
import {
  Button,
  Heading,
  VStack,
  Stack,
  HStack,
  Box,
  CircularProgress,
  Text,
  CircularProgressLabel,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useState, useRef, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SettingsContext } from '../helpers/SettingsContext';
import PomodoroSettings from './PomodoroSettings';

// Pomodoro
const Pomodoro = () => {
  //Timer
  const { newTimer, setNewTimer } = useContext(SettingsContext);
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(true);
  const [secondsLeft, setSecondsLeft] = useState(newTimer.work);

  const secondsLeftRef = useRef(secondsLeft);
  const isPausedRef = useRef(isPaused);
  const modeRef = useRef(newTimer.active);

  function tick() {
    secondsLeftRef.current--;
    setSecondsLeft(secondsLeftRef.current);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function switchMode() {
      const nextMode = modeRef.current === 'work' ? 'break' : 'work';
      const nextSeconds =
        (nextMode === 'work' ? newTimer.work : newTimer.short) * 60;

      setNewTimer({
        work: newTimer.work,
        short: newTimer.short,
        long: newTimer.long,
        active: nextMode,
      });
      modeRef.current = nextMode;

      console.log(nextMode);
      console.log('Next: ' + nextSeconds);
      setSecondsLeft(nextSeconds); // This does not update secondsLeft
      console.log('SecondsLeft: ' + secondsLeft);
      secondsLeftRef.current = nextSeconds;
    }

    secondsLeftRef.current = newTimer.work * 60;
    setSecondsLeft(secondsLeftRef.current);

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (isPausedRef.current) {
        return;
      }
      if (secondsLeftRef.current === 0) {
        return switchMode();
      }

      tick();
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [newTimer, setNewTimer]);

  const totalSeconds =
    newTimer.active === 'work' ? newTimer.work * 60 : newTimer.short * 60;
  const percentage = Math.round((secondsLeft / totalSeconds) * 100);

  const minutes = Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60);
  let seconds = secondsLeft % 60;
  if (seconds < 10) seconds = '0' + seconds;

  // Start / Pause
  const handleButton = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (isPaused) {
      setIsPaused(!isPaused);
      isPausedRef.current = false;
    } else {
      setIsPaused(!isPaused);
      isPausedRef.current = true;
    }
  };
  // console.log(percentage)
  // console.log(newTimer.active)
  // console.log(secondsLeft)
  // console.log(totalSeconds)
  return (
    <div>
      <Heading as='h4' size='md'>
        {' '}
        Pomodoro{' '}
      </Heading>
      <VStack>
        <HStack>
          <Button variant='ghost'>Pomodoro</Button>
          <Button variant='ghost'>Short Break</Button>
          <Button variant='ghost'>Long Break</Button>
        </HStack>
        <CircularProgress
          value={percentage}
          color={newTimer.active === 'work' ? 'red.400' : 'green.400'}
          size='200px'
          thickness='10px'
        >
          <CircularProgressLabel>
            <Text fontSize='3xl'>{minutes + ':' + seconds}</Text>
          </CircularProgressLabel>
        </CircularProgress>
        <HStack>
          <Button variant='outline' onClick={handleButton}>
            {isPaused ? <div> START </div> : <div> STOP </div>}
          </Button>
          <PomodoroSettings />
        </HStack>
      </VStack>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pomodoro;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is too much going on in one `eseEffect()`. The initial value of `newTimer.work` is not modified so each re-render will set `secondsLeftRef` to the same initial value.
Since `useEffect()`updates a context object, the component will re-render on every iteration, setting `secondsLeftRef` to its initial value.

Answer (score 0):

useState uses array const [value, setValue] like this. It might be just an error in this declaration of newTimer.

Comment: The useState comes from another .js page, which was why I used useContext to import it over and hence { }.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the problem is but few things I noticed that you can try to fix or improve in your code -

1. Do not use or assign `context` or `props` value in `useState` as you are doing it for `secondsLeft`, reason is that `useState` is supposed to run once when `component` gets rendered first time and you might not get value for `newTimer.work` on very first `render`.
   For this you can use `useEffect` and `newTimer` in dependency array.

```
const [secondsLeft, setSecondsLeft] = useState(newTimer.work);
```

2. You are trying to log `secondsLeft` immediatly after calling `setSecondsLeft` this will not give you correct value because setting state is `asynchronous` in `react` so it will not be available on next line after calling set state.

```
setSecondsLeft(nextSeconds);
console.log('SecondsLeft: ' + secondsLeft);
```

3. One last thing I noticed looking at your code is that it's possible that you might be registering multiple `setInterval` because below line is responsible for clearing `interval` only when component gets `unmount` but your `useEffect` will get called multiple times based on its `dependencies`.

```
return () => clearInterval(interval);
```

Try to debug your code for above 3rd point and if that's the problem you
can try `clearing` your `interval` in start of `useEffect` or add
some conditions to make sure it will get register once to get
expected results.

`Note` - I have not tried executing your code, but let me know if this helps or if I can improve my answer in any way.