# Pomodoro Timer in ReactJS - Multiple instances of setIntervals running and clearInterval does not work to reset the timer

Tags: reactjs, timer, setinterval

I redid my Pomodoro timer but it still does not work.

This time, I have multiple instances of timers running at once.

The handlePomodoro, handleShort and handleLong functions do not work as intended.

When users trigger the above onClick effects, it is suppose to reset the timer to the desired timings. (Which it does)

However, when I run the timer, the timer keeps jumping between previous instances and the new instance.

Example:
I start with a Pomodoro ('work') time. The timer runs perfect.
But when I switch to 'break' using the handleShort function before the first timer ends. It resets the timer, and displays the correct 'break' time. The only issue is, when i start the timer again, it runs the previous and new time concurrently. So it will show like:
3:48
3:52
3:47
3:51

Please help with this clearInterval isssue.

```
import {Button,
    Heading,
    VStack, 
    Stack, 
    HStack,
    Box,
    CircularProgress, 
    Text,
    CircularProgressLabel } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { set } from 'mongoose';
import { useState, useRef, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { SettingsContext } from '../helpers/SettingsContext';
import PomodoroSettings from './PomodoroSettings';

// Pomodoro 
const Pomodoro = () => {

    //Timer
    const { newTimer, setNewTimer } = useContext(SettingsContext);
    const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(true);
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(newTimer.work);
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('work');
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    // const [isReset, setIsReset] = useState(false);
    var isReset = false;

    const secondsLeftRef = useRef(minutes * 60 + seconds);
    const isPausedRef = useRef(isPaused);


    useEffect(() => {
        
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (isPausedRef.current) {
                return;
            } 
            if (isReset) {
                console.log("reset")
                isReset = false;
                return () => clearInterval(interval);
            }
            clearInterval(interval);
            secondsLeftRef.current--;
            if (seconds === 0) {
                if (minutes !== 0) {
                    setSeconds(59);
                    setMinutes(minutes - 1);
                } else {
                    if (mode === 'work') {
                        let minutes = newTimer.short;
                        let seconds = 0;

                        setMinutes(minutes)
                        setSeconds(seconds)
                        setMode('short')
                        secondsLeftRef.current = minutes * 60 + seconds;
                        isPausedRef.current = true;
                        setIsPaused(true);
                    } else if (mode === 'short') {
                        let minutes = newTimer.work;
                        let seconds = 0;

                        setMinutes(minutes)
                        setSeconds(seconds)
                        setMode('work')
                        secondsLeftRef.current = minutes * 60 + seconds;
                        isPausedRef.current = true;
                        setIsPaused(true);
                    } else if (mode === 'long') {
                        let minutes = newTimer.work;
                        let seconds = 0;

                        setMinutes(minutes)
                        setSeconds(seconds)
                        setMode('work')
                        secondsLeftRef.current = minutes * 60 + seconds;
                        isPausedRef.current = true;
                        setIsPaused(true);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                setSeconds(seconds - 1);
            }
            
            
        }, 1000)
    }, [seconds, mode])

    const timerMinutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
    const timerSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
    const totalSeconds = mode === 'work'
    ? newTimer.work * 60
    : newTimer.short * 60;
    const percentage = Math.round(secondsLeftRef.current / totalSeconds * 100);
    
    // Start / Pause    
    const handleButton = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (isPaused) {
            setIsPaused(!isPaused);
            isPausedRef.current = false;
        } else {
            setIsPaused(!isPaused);
            isPausedRef.current = true;

        }
    }

    // Pomodoro Button
    const handlePomodoro = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setMode('work');
        let minutes = newTimer.work;
        let seconds = 0;

        setMinutes(minutes)
        setSeconds(seconds)
        secondsLeftRef.current = minutes * 60 + seconds;
        isPausedRef.current = true;
        setIsPaused(true);
        isReset = true;
    }

    // Short Break Button
    const handleShort = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setMode('short');
        let minutes = newTimer.short;
        let seconds = 0;

        setMinutes(minutes)
        setSeconds(seconds)
        secondsLeftRef.current = minutes * 60 + seconds;
        isPausedRef.current = true;
        setIsPaused(true);
        isReset = true;
    }
    
    // Long Break Button
    const handleLong = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setMode('long');
        let minutes = newTimer.long;
        let seconds = 0;

        setMinutes(minutes)
        setSeconds(seconds)
        secondsLeftRef.current = minutes * 60 + seconds;
        isPausedRef.current = true;
        setIsPaused(true);
        isReset = true;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Heading as='h4' size='md'> Pomodoro </Heading>
            <VStack>
                <HStack>
                <Button variant='ghost' onClick={handlePomodoro}>
                    Pomodoro
                </Button>
                <Button variant='ghost' onClick={handleShort}>
                    Short Break
                </Button>
                <Button variant='ghost' onClick={handleLong}>
                    Long Break
                </Button>
                </HStack>
                <CircularProgress value={percentage} color={mode === 'work' ? 'red.400' : 'green.400'} size='200px' thickness='10px'>
                    <CircularProgressLabel> 
                        <Text fontSize='3xl'>{timerMinutes}:{timerSeconds}</Text>
                    </CircularProgressLabel>
                </CircularProgress>
                <HStack>
                    <Button variant='outline' onClick={handleButton}>
                        { isPaused ? <div> START </div> : <div> STOP </div> }
                    </Button>
                    <PomodoroSettings />
                </HStack>
            </VStack>
            

        </div>
    )
}

export default Pomodoro
```

Comment: I have already mentioned this point in your last question's answer - please check here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591712/12541413

Comment: Hi, I tried logging the clear interval in this part of the useEffect, but it still doesn't work.
```
 if (isReset) {
                console.log("reset")
                isReset = false;
                return () => clearInterval(interval);
            }
```
The console will log the "reset" string but the clearInterval doesn't work... or i'm using it wrongly

Comment: you are trying to clear `interval` inside `setInterval` instead try doing `return () => clearInterval(intervalId);` at the end of `useEffect`. and remove `clearInterval` code from `setInterval`